# Why read units consumed by dynamodb appears as fraction and not as whole number in cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-billing

I have a dynamodb table with an item having two string values. One is around 10 bytes in size and other is 8192 bytes (8KB). After I read this item from lambda, I saw cloud watch showing read units consumed as 1.5. Please refer attached image. One read unit is 4KB in size (as per the docs) and it gets rounded up to the next 4KB. So I was hoping to see 2 read units consumed and not 1.5. Any suggestions on how it is computed and how much eventually is billed?

[image]

Comment: Eventually-consistent reads consume only 0.5 RCU.  Is that they type of read you did?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I used eventually consistent read. I found AWS doc which says it consumes lesser units. You are right. Can you please post your comment as an answer to make me mark it as accepted answer? Thanks!